# $product->save(); causing an error - when changing product qty

Tags: php, magento

I am creating a custom module.

I am testing the ability to update a products quantity.

I have created a bare bones magento module and began testing with code inside indexController.php here is my code:

```
public function indexAction() {

    //Just grabbing sku# 62701 for testing...
    $tempProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 62701 );

    $stockData['qty'] = 300;
    $tempProduct->setStockData($stockData);

    $tempProduct->save(); 

}
```

By having the last line in there i get the error.

From the error log:

a:5:{i:0;s:46:"Invalid method Varien_Object::save(Array
(
)

Followed by the stack trace...

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to save data that seemed to work in my scenario (not sure why it worked) here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7608195/1110880

The code that made it work was the following:

```
    $productId = $tempProduct->getId();
    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);
    $stockItem->setData('qty', $qty);

    $stockItem->save();
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 5):

I had to look into this issue and found the problem. The whole stock data/item interface is a bit tricky.

### Problem

`Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract->loadByAttribute` uses collection-loading on collection `catalog/product_collection` with a limit of 1.

Stock items of products in that collection are loaded via the event observer `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer->addStockStatusToCollection` which listens to event `catalog_product_collection_load_after`. `addStockStatusToCollection` loads stock items of products only if flag `require_stock_items` is set `true`.

In case of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract->loadByAttribute` this flag isn't set so we end up with `$product->_data['stock_item']` being of type `Varien_Object` (see `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Status` lines 488-491).

This causes error

> Invalid method Varien_Object::save...

on `$product->save`.

I recommend solution 1 if you save the product anyway and want the stock update to happen in the same transaction. Solution 2 only sets stock data so it avoids calling expensive `$product->save`.

### Solution 1

Use an additional load on the product: this loads `$product->_data['stock_item']` properly.

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 62701 );
$tempProduct->load($tempProduct->getId());
```

This is an additonal read transaction on the database which slows things down.

### Solution 2

As in other answers suggested use the class `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item` directly. But you have reference the product correctly via call to `setProduct` to have working code both for new and existing stock items.

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getId());
$stockItem->setProduct($product)
    ->setData('stock_id', Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock::DEFAULT_STOCK_ID)
    ->setData('qty', 1)
    ->setData('is_in_stock', 1)
    ->setData('manage_stock', 1)
    ->setData('use_config_manage_stock', 0)
    ->setData('use_config_backorders', 0)
    ->setData('backorders', 0)
    ->setData('use_config_max_sale_qty', 0)
    ->setData('max_sale_qty', 1)                
    ->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see two potential problems.

1. Are you sure that `loadByAttribute('sku', 62701 )` can *only* return one item? (That error [has shown up](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/202163/) when people have tried to update more than one thing at once.)
2. `$stockData` is not defined. At a minimum it would be safer to define it.

It looks like you're missing something like this:

```
$stockData = $tempProduct->getStockData();
```

Comment: 1. Yes, it only loaded one item, I echoed $tempProduct->getName and only name showed up.
2. I added the $stockData definition, it still seems to give me the error.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably doing something wrong, but I had the same problem and this helped:

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getId());
$stockItem->setProductId($product->getId());
$stockItem->setStockId(Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock::DEFAULT_STOCK_ID);
```